# Term begins with a letter

Tags: terms

I had a template that relied on

`$terms = get_terms( "ingredient", array( 'name__like' => $letter ) );`

to return all posts where the custom taxonomy `ingredient` begins with `$letter`.

The behaviour of `name__like` [was changed in WP 3.7](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms#Parameters) to a text search instead of beginning.

What function can I use to achieve the results I had before? Do I need a custom query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to filter the query, which you can do with the `terms_clauses` hook. This is very similar to G-M's solution but does not require a prefix on your search string.

```
function old_style_name_like_wpse_123298($clauses) {
  remove_filter('term_clauses','old_style_name_like_wpse_123298');
  $pattern = '|(name LIKE )\'%(.+%)\'|';
  $clauses['where'] = preg_replace($pattern,'$1 \'$2\'',$clauses['where']);
  return $clauses;
}
add_filter('terms_clauses','old_style_name_like_wpse_123298');
// $letter = 'str'; // test
$terms = get_terms( "ingredient", array( 'name__like' => $letter ) )
```

Comment: Good one (+1), however once it will affect any `get_terms` calls that include `'name__like'` or `'search'` argument, you should include in the pattern some (all?) not alphanumeric chars, once they are legal taxonomy name args... (`LIKE` clause is applyed to term name, not to term slug). Probably `$pattern = '|(name LIKE )\'%(.+%)\'|';` can be a good choice because query is already sanitized by WP.

Comment: @G-M : the filter removes itself so it should only effect the next use of `get_terms` and, yes, I am sure the regex could be tweaked :)

Comment: E.g.: `add_filter('terms_clauses','old_style_name_like_wpse_123298');` `get_terms( "category", array( 'name__like' => '¿' ) );` to retrieve categories starting with '¿' will not work as expected.. in spanish-speaking countries people use WordPress too ;)

Comment: @G-M : edited per your suggestion

Comment: I'd like to but I can't +1 again :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a trick.

Prepend to the letter you want to search a *strange* string:

```
$letter = '§§§' . 'a'; // strange string plus the letter you want to search
```

Then apply a filter to `terms_clauses` hook:

```
add_filter('terms_clauses', 'replace_name__like_for_ingredients', 10, 3);

$terms = get_terms( "ingredient", array( 'name__like' => $letter ) );
```

Finally use that function to remove the `%` preceding the *strange* string and the *strange* string itself:

```
function replace_name__like_for_ingredient( $pieces, $taxonomies, $args ) {
  if ( in_array('ingredient', $taxonomies) ) {
    // replace the perc sign plus strange string with empty string so
    // LIKE '%§§§a%' become LIKE 'a%'
    $pieces['where'] = str_replace("%§§§", '', $pieces['where']);
  }
  return $pieces;
}
```

**Untested**.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the previous answers, so I'll add this note here in case anyone else faces this problem too:
The above wasn't working for me, so I replaced:

```
$pattern = '|(name LIKE )\'%(.+%)\'|';
```

with

```
$pattern = '|(name LIKE )\'{.*?}(.+{.*?})\'|';
```

as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47840519/listing-custom-taxonomy-terms-by-first-letter-using-name-like-does-not-work-ev

Answer (score 0):

Based on gmazaap's reply, I got this:

```
$terms_array = [
    'taxonomy' => 'pa_myattr',
    'name__like' => '§§§' . 'A'
];
$terms = get_terms($terms_array);

add_filter('terms_clauses', 'replace_name__like_for_product_attribute', 10, 3);
function replace_name__like_for_product_attribute($pieces, $taxonomies, $args)
{
  if (in_array('pa_myattr', $taxonomies)) {
    // replace the perc sign plus strange string with empty string so
    // LIKE '{abc..}§§§a{abc...}' become LIKE 'A%'
    $pieces['where'] = preg_replace('/(.* LIKE ).*§§§([A-Z])(.*)/', '$1\'$2$3', $pieces['where']);
  }
  return $pieces;
}
```

Tested with WordPress 5.2.2

Had to modify the regular str_replace with a preg_match because now WordPress seems to add something like a hash to protect SQL injections. Since this string seems to be random between queries the only solution is to use regex.