# Wordpress tax query use operator LIKE

Tags: tax-query

I have taxonomy color which  is associated with a custom post type. I am listing all the post meta and the taxonomy  in a table. I have a option in the table  to search  the posts matching the search value.

when search key is entered it will do a ajax call to get the the posts.

this is the query to get all the posts matching the search string.

```
function get_query_posts_custom($post_id,$start,$length)  {
    //get_posts arguments
    $args =  array(
        'post_type'     => 'custom_post',
        'post_status'   => array('publish'),
        'numberposts'   => $length,
        'offset'        => $start,
        'orderby'       => 'menu_order',
        'order'         => 'asc',
        'post_parent'   => $_product->id
    );


    //get custom post taxonomy
    $taxonomies = (array) maybe_unserialize(get_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_taxonomy', true));
    if(empty($attributes)) {
        $taxonomies = array();
    }

    $meta_keys  = array('type','code','key');       
    if(!empty($search)) {
        foreach($meta_keys as $meta_key) {
            $meta_query[] = array(
                        'key'   => $meta_key,
                        'value' => $search,
                        'compare'   => 'LIKE';
                    );

        }

        $args['meta_query'] = $meta_query;
        $tax_query = array();

        foreach($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {
            $tax_query  = array(
                'taxonomy'  =>  $taxonomy;
                'field' =>  'slug';
                'terms' =>  $search;
                'operator'  => 'LIKE';
            );
        }
        if(count($tax_query)) {
            $args['tax_query'] = $tax_query;
        }
    }
    $results    = get_posts($args);
            return $results;
}
```

How to get the posts that matches the search string of a taxonomy?

I searched the wordpress function reference  it says only operator allowed to tax_query are 'IN,NOT IN, OR and AND')
 can I use the LIKE operator?

Comment: Have you tried the solution in this thread: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/123298/term-begins-with-a-letter?

Comment: I tried to get the term ID matching the search using the get_terms function with name_like arugment and generate the tax_query with IN operator.

Comment: Does the get_posts support the operator argument in the tax_query. Function Reference does not mention anything about the tax_query with operator. Only in WP_Query it is explained.

Answer (score 5):

The only option you have is to write your own SQL into the [`posts_clauses`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_clauses) filter, where you get an array of the `JOIN`, `WHERE`, `ORDER`, etc. clauses that you can alter, add to, remove, etc.

One MAJOR MAJOR note on this, is ALWAYS use the global `$wpdb`'s [`prepare`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) function, which will sanitize all your lovely datas. You don't want to be allowing any type of injection through your search term custom queries. :)

Comment: :) Added a note for keeping your database safe as well.

Answer (score 5):

As stated in other answers you cannot simply do a `LIKE`-wise search using `tax_query`.

What you can do is either altering the `SQL` statement using filters as suggested by @Eric Holmes which is an advanced technique. You need to know what you are doing.
Or you could just make a separate query loading the taxonomy terms first (using `LIKE`) and then loading the actual posts.

Here is a simple sample for loading posts that are in relation to any terms matching a `LIKE` compare against the `$search` variable.

```
//  load the terms using LIKE
$termIds = get_terms([
    'name__like' => $search,
    'fields' => 'ids'
]);


//  load the posts using the found term IDs
$posts = get_posts([
    'tax_query' => [
        'relation' => 'OR',
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'yourtaxonomy',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $termIds,
        ],
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'othertaxonomy',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $termIds,
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Comment: this is clever and cleaner, thanks.

Comment: On the `tax_query` you would need to use `term_id` for the field value.

Answer (score 2):

[WP_Tax_Query](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L625) respectively the Taxonomy Parameter of  [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) or [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts#Taxonomy_Parameters) does only take the following for the `operator` argument:

> 'operator' string (optional)
>       Possible values: 'AND', 'IN' or 'NOT IN'.
>       Default: 'IN'

So you can not use `LIKE` as `operator`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to use compare arguments/operators in taxonomy queries (but in meta queries, yes.)

so, this modified part should behave as using 'LIKE' by default:

```
foreach($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {
            $tax_query  = array(
                'taxonomy'  =>  $taxonomy;
                'field' =>  'slug';
                'terms' =>  $search;
            );
        }
```