# Wordpress get all post with like in terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, get-posts, terms

I have a wordpress site, which has post and custom taxonomy. I want all post of a particular taxonomy with like query.

For example: 
Table: wp_post
post_id
100

Table: term_relationship
post_id  term_taxonomy_id
100      154

Table: term_taxonomy
id   term_id  taxonomy
154  155      business_listing

Table: term
id  name   slug
155 Basket basket

I want all the post of Basket term in wordpress.
[image]

Comment: Hi @Rajiv, welcome to WPSE! In order to better answer your question, please update it with what you've tried already and what errors or messages you're getting when you try what you have now. Narrowing down a question to a single issue will help us point you in the right direction instead of having to guess what you mean and going off on a tangent.

Comment: Thanks for response. Please check image now with above script. I can fetch all taxomony and there posts but I want like query in taxonomy

Answer (score 0):

'LIKE' isn't supported by the current version of [`WP_Tax_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_tax_query/), so you'll need to write a custom query. This answer from a couple of years ago still seems to be the best approach: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/133805/26317.