# A loop with all articles with certain text strings in tags

Tags: loop, query, tags

What I want to achieve: A loop that display's all articles with a certain text string in their tags.

**For example:**

If I have an article tagged with "*coffeemug*" and one "*coffeebean*". Now I want to display them both because of the text string "*coffee*".

A default query like this:

```
query_posts( 'tag=coffee' );
```

will display none of it. It will just work for articles tagged exactly with "*coffee*"

And yes, I know, I can use an array for both tags. But in my case I don't know all tags which might be used in the future. I just know that some of them will start with "*coffee*". 
There can be hundreds of tags...or just the two above...but I want to catch 'em all.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @birgire's always-useful comments, I did write a workaround for you. What I'm doing is to first find the terms that match the search string. Then, based on the found terms I will do a query in those.

```
function wpse_posts_by_tagname( $string ) {

    // Let's find every tag that has 'coffee' in it's name
    $term_args = array(
        'taxonomy'             => 'post_tag',
        'fields'               => 'ids',
        'name__like'           => $string,
        // 'description__like' => $string, // You can also search in description. 
        // 'search'            => $string, // We can even search in the term's name! 
    );
    $terms = get_terms( $term_args );

    // Let's make an array of term IDs
    if ( empty( $terms ) || is_wp_error( $terms ) )
        esc_html_e( 'No matches found', 'text-domain' );

    // Alright we got'em, now query based on these
    $query_args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'tag__in'        => (array) $terms,
        'posts_per_page' => 10 // Optional limitation of posts per page
    );
    $tag_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

    if( $tag_query->have_posts() ){
        while( $tag_query->have_posts() ){
            $tag_query->the_post();
            the_title( 
                sprintf( '<h2><a href="%s">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ),
                '</a></h2>' 
            );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
        esc_html_e( 'No matches found', 'text-domain' );
    }
}
```

Also it's worth noting that you should use `WP_Query` instead of `query_posts`. There are endless articles on the internet about this, so I'm just gonna skip this part.

Comment: I don't think LIKE is supported as tax query operator  and shouldn't it be post_tag ?

Comment: I guess many have tried the same, so you could mentioned that `LIKE` isn't supported. A workaround might be to find the terms with `get_terms()` using e.g. the `name__like` argument, and feed it to the `WP_Query` tax query? Or writing  [custom solutions via filters](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/133752/wordpress-tax-query-use-operator-like)? Or better yet, suggest a proper taxonomy structure instead?

Comment: Thanks for the comments @birgire! Would you be kind and see if the update is written properly?

Comment: sure,I think the get_terms input argument should be a single array.and the_permalink() and the_title() echo but don't return the value. Resetting post data might be good too afterwards. Might also consider returning only ids from get_terms() withe 'fields' => 'ids'.. Ps: just to note that my suggestion might not scale well for huge number of terms.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issues, all set now. `get_term` does also have a string format (`get_terms('taxonomy',$args)`) but I suppose it's deprecated? Seems like I was quite sleepy while writing this, so many issues :P