# getting posts by tags

Tags: wp-query, search, tags, rest-api

i use below code for getting posts by word tag

```
$search_songs = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'songs',
        'tax_query' => array (
            array (
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $search_query,
            )
        )
    );  

    $new_query = new WP_Query( $search_songs );
    $search_songs_posts = $new_query->posts;╨
```

**But** by this code it return posts that have **exactly** word tag

**EXAMPLE** :
when search "**akam**" it return posts that have "akam" tag , 
**BUT** when search "**aka**" (**a part of word**) it return **nothings**
i want to when search "aka" it return all post that have tags that include my arg("aka") not just exactly word

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your query as:

```
$search_songs = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'songs',
        'tag' => $search_query,//use tag to filter posts
    );
```

[For more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272997/wordpress-trying-to-get-posts-by-tag)

Comment: thanks but it's like my code and not return if $search_query = a part of tag word

Comment: Do you want to apply `LIKE` search on tags?

Answer (score 0):

As per document here
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters

If you are using tax query it only supports ‘IN’, ‘NOT IN’, ‘AND’, ‘EXISTS’ and ‘NOT EXISTS’.

So if you want to search "aka" and return posts with "akam" tag you need to do this using like query.

You can check this answer for reference :
[Wordpress tax query use operator LIKE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/133752/wordpress-tax-query-use-operator-like)