# Filter and list posts of a custom taxonomy

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have a custom Taxonomy called 'owner' and it has multiple posts as owner names (Using as a category) so I can filter posts by 'owner' taxonomy.

I'm trying to make an index page of all owner names which starts with letter 'A'. I was able to list all the owners with following code.

```
foreach ( get_terms( 'owner' ) as $o ){
        $owner = $o -> name;
        if($owner[0] === 'A'){
            // Coding here...
        }
}
```

The issue I face is I want to show a pagination at the bottom of the page because there are hundreds of authors stars with 'A'.

Comment: You should not be naming your taxonomy `author`, `author` is a **reserved** term

Comment: actually I have changed that now to a different name. However the issue is still exists.

Comment: Might be best to manually create pagination using URL (`$_GET`) variables and your own custom prev/next links.

Comment: Any code snippets?

Comment: I'm using my own shortcode to display owners. I just want to add the pagination instead of displaying all the owners.

Comment: Would this work? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22093/how-to-paginate-a-list-of-tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before we look at pagination, from what I have picked up in your question, you only need terms starting with `A`. If so, you can make use of the `name__like` parameter in `get_terms` to get terms only that starts with `A`. Just a note on that, the operation of the parameter was changed in Wordpress V3.7, so you will need to apply the following filter for this to work as expected (*Credit to @s_ha_dum, see his answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/123306/31545). NOTE: The code requires PHP 5.4+*)

```
add_filter( 'terms_clauses', function ($clauses) 
{
  remove_filter( 'term_clauses', __FUNCTION__ );

  $pattern = '|(name LIKE )\'%(.+%)\'|';
  $clauses['where'] = preg_replace($pattern,'$1 \'$2\'',$clauses['where']);
  return $clauses;
});

$terms = get_terms( 'ownwer' ['name__like' => 'A'] );
```

To paginate a list of terms, we need:

- The current page number
- The total amount of terms in the list
- Total amont of pages there will be

To get the page number of the current page or any page is easy. This will work on all pages including static front pages and single post pages

```
if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
    $current_page = get_query_var( 'paged' );
} elseif ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) {
    $current_page = get_query_var( 'page' );
} else {
    $current_page = 1;
}
```

We now need to know the total amount of terms from the taxonomy. Here we can use either [`wp_count_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_count_terms/), which uses `get_terms()` or use `get_terms()` itself. Remember, if we used the filter to get terms by a specific letter/name, the filter will be applied to this run of `get_terms()`/`wp_count_terms()` as well as we are making using of a closure

```
$terms_count = get_terms( 'owner', ['name__like' => 'A', 'fields' => 'count'] );
```

Now we have the total amount of terms matching our criteria. Just remember, if your are going to use `wp_count_terms()`, just remember to set `hide_empty` to true if you do not need to include empty terms. By default, `wp_count_terms()` sets this to `false`

Now we can calculate our maximum amount of pages

```
// Set the amount of terms we need to display per page
$terms_per_page = 10;
// Get the total amount of pages
$max_num_pages = $terms_count / $terms_per_page;
```

To get pagination links to next and previous pages, it is really easy. The only thing a pagination function ever needs to know from any query is the maximum amount of pages, nothing else. It does not need to know what it should paginate. So we can simply use the `next_posts_link()` and `previous_posts_link()` functions. You can also make use `paginate_links()` or even write your own function to suite your needs. Just remember to pass `$max_num_pages` as the maximum amount of pages to the pagination function

```
next_posts_link( 'Next terms', $max_num_pages );
previous_posts_link( 'Previous terms' );
```

The only thing we still need to do is to paginate `get_terms()`, which is also really easy. We will make use of the `offset` parameter to offset the terms according to page and `number` to get the required amount of terms per page

```
// Calculate offset
$offset = ( $current_page == 1) ? 0 : ( ($current_page - 1) * $terms_per_page );
// Setup our arguments
$args = [
    'number' => $terms_per_page,
    'offset' => $offset
];
```

We can now put everything together

### ALL TOGETHER NOW

Just before we do, a couple of important notes

- All of the code is untested
- The code needs at least PHP 5.4, which is the absolute minimum PHP version you should be running at time of this post
- Modify and tear apart as needed

Here is the code, finally

```
add_filter( 'terms_clauses', function ($clauses) 
{
  remove_filter( 'term_clauses', __FUNCTION__ );

  $pattern = '|(name LIKE )\'%(.+%)\'|';
  $clauses['where'] = preg_replace($pattern,'$1 \'$2\'',$clauses['where']);
  return $clauses;
});

$taxonomy = 'owner';

$terms_count = get_terms( $taxonomy, ['name__like' => 'A', 'fields' => 'count'] );
if ( $terms_count && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {

    if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
        $current_page = get_query_var( 'paged' );
    } elseif ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) {
        $current_page = get_query_var( 'page' );
    } else {
        $current_page = 1;
    }


    // Set the amount of terms we need to display per page
    $terms_per_page = 10;
    // Get the total amount of pages
    $max_num_pages = $terms_count / $terms_per_page;

    // Calculate offset
    $offset = ( $current_page == 1) ? 0 : ( ($current_page - 1) * $terms_per_page );
    // Setup our arguments
    $args = [
        'number' => $terms_per_page,
        'offset' => $offset,
        'name__like' => 'A'
    ];
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );

    // Do what you need to do with $terms

    next_posts_link( 'Next terms', $max_num_pages );
    previous_posts_link( 'Previous terms' );

}
```

Comment: This made me think of *Yellow Submarine* :)

Comment: @ialocin Hahaha, great oldtimer. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the code. However this is displaying all the owners. Not only people starts with 'A' but also everyone  :(

Comment: `name_like` should be `name__like`

Comment: I have updated all instance which should be `name__like`. If you have any further issues, feel free to leave me a comment. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was able to do a custom pagination ( << 1 2 3 .. 20 .. 35 36 37 >> ) code by adding some modification to your code. This helped me lots. I'm awarding you my points to you.

Comment: My pleasure, glad you were able to solve this. Enjoy ;-)

Comment: Btw, do you know how to add page number (Page 2 of 100) to the title? to make it more SEO friendly?

Comment: Check my pagination function [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/172818/31545). You will need to make a few alterations as by default, it uses the query object, you need to convert it to work with the integer value from `$max_num_pages`. If you have an issue, feel free to ask a new question with all the specifics :-)

Comment: I'm using Yoast SEO. So I was able to add a filter. Now fine :)
Only one issue is adding total number of pages to the filter :(
Anyway to pass the `$max_num_pages` value to that function?

Comment: Please post a new question, make sure to post the code you have. Will be happy to look at it

Answer (score 2):

If you want to only visually limit the number of displayed names, you could use javascript or jQuery and CSS to paginate the results into smaller chunks that visitors could read through. But this will not create real, distinct pages.

I will update this answer with a piece of code I used to limit a long list at X numbers of items, that you browse with a previous / next link, but also can easily add a numbered pagination to.

Otherwise, a quick search produced that (WordPress) plugin, but I have not tested it, and am not sure about compatibility with current WP versions:
http://wordpress.mfields.org/plugins/taxonomy-list-shortcode/
It seems it does precisely what you want (PHP) in the form of a shortcode.

Update: I had scavenged most of this code from somewhere and modified it to suit my needs. In my application I used functions to disable and enable elements etc, which I reverted here into straight jQuery, so take into account there might be a piece or another of custom code that remains there that will need changing to work with your thing.

This in jQuery:

```
var paginate_list = function(items) {
    var pageSize = items; // How many items per page
    var numberOfPages = Math.ceil(($('.lists li').length)/pageSize); // I used list items but you can use anything, this counts how many elements in total, and divides by the previous to know how many pages total
    var pageCounter = $("#current-page"); // I store the current page number in a hidden input value for my particular situation but you can keep track of it anyway else
    var prev = $('#navigation .key-prev');
    var next = $('#navigation .key-next'); // the navigation buttons
    pageCounter.val(1); // initialize to page 1, also peculiar to my application
    prev.attr('disable', true); // disable prev button if page 1
    if ( numberOfPages <= 1 ) {
        next.attr('disable', true); // disable next if only 1 page
    }
    next.on('click', function () {
        // calculate the list offset
        $(".lists li:nth-child(-n+" + ((pageCounter.val() * pageSize) + pageSize) + ")").show();
        $(".lists li:nth-child(-n+" + pageCounter.val() * pageSize + ")").hide();
        pageCounter.val(Number(pageCounter.val()) + 1); // update page counter
        if (pageCounter.val() != 1) {
            prev.attr('disable', false); // enable previous button
        }
        if (pageCounter.val() == numberOfPages) {
            $(this).attr('disable', true); // disable the next button when you reach the end
        }
    });
    prev.on('click', function () {
        // the same in reverse
        pageCounter.val(Number(pageCounter.val()) - 1);
        $(".lists li").hide();
        $(".lists li:nth-child(-n+" + (pageCounter.val() * pageSize) + ")").show();
        $(".lists li:nth-child(-n+" + ((pageCounter.val() * pageSize) - pageSize) + ")").hide();
        if (pageCounter.val() == 1) {
            $(this).attr('disable', true);
        } 
        if (pageCounter.val() < numberOfPages) {
            next.attr('disable', false);
        } 
    });
};
```

And it would work with lists like this:

```
<ul class="lists">
  <li><!-- your first item --></li>
  <li><!-- your second item --></li>
  <li><!-- your third item --></li>
  <li><!-- your fourth item etc... --></li>
</ul>
```